# Can't Right-Click on Gnome-Shell Panel to Add Extension

Tags: gnome, 11.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

**Problem**

I've upgraded to 11.10 today, and have been toying with gnome-shell extensions - gnome-shell version 3.2.0.

When it comes to add one to the top panel, I have hit a brick wall. Right-clicking on the panel does nothing.

Am I doing something wrong - is one supposed to add extensions to the top panel by some other method?

**Tried**

- "Installing" an extension
- holding `alt` while right-clicking on top panel

Answer (score 4):

you can't add extensions by right clicking the panel. You have to create a dir in ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/extension_name@your_host

and create there 2 files: extension.js and metadata.json

and add code to whatever you want to add onto panel to extension.js and some info into metadata.json

in gnome-shell 3.0.x in .js you have to add function main() { }
in gnome-shell 3.2.x: function enable() { /* code to execute on enabling this extension */ }
function disable() { } and function init() { }

Comment: I've done that - what I want to do is add one of the extensions that I've prepared in the manner described to the panel. For example: http://projecthamster.wordpress.com/2011/07/07/update-for-gnome-shell-users/

Answer (score 0):

To get the "Add to Panel" menu, you need to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>super</kbd> <kbd>right-click</kbd>; see also: 
[Panel settings not appearing on right-click in gnome](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125891/panel-settings-not-appearing-on-right-click-in-gnome)