# Panel settings not appearing on right-click in gnome

Tags: gnome-panel

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I switched to Gnome classic from unity as I'm more comfortable with the former. However, I couldn't find where the panel setting are. Usually a drop down menu appears on right-clicking the top and bottom panels. But it doesn't happen now.

I need the panel settings so as to auto hide the panels (as my netbook screen is quite small!) as well as to add the "system monitor" applet to the panel which is really useful.

Where can I find the panel settings?

Comment: Maybe this is a duplicate of question [remove unwanted shortcut gnome classic](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80142/remove-unwanted-shortcut-gnome-classic)

Comment: And... none of these are working for me :(

Comment: None of the answers below work for me. I am using Ubuntu 21.10 and Gnome 40.4.0.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Try this :

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Super</kbd>+ Right Click

Comment: Just Alt-Right click works. No need for Super

Comment: i was getting the same issue, but Alt + Super + Right Click works for me. But after i edited the Panel settings, i unchecked the "Expand" option, and now panel shrunk to accommodate only the items present on the panel, there is no "empty" space on the panel where i right click and get the Preferences back to enable "expand" again. Only options i get are to move the item on the panel and remove it from the panel. there is no way to activate "add to Panel". plz help!!!

Comment: as jay mentions in his answer, `Super` is `Windows` key

Comment: i can verify that alt-rightclick does *not* work. you need the full super-alt-rightclick chord.

Comment: Not working in Gnome 3 in RHEL 7.2 distribution...

Comment: super+alt+rightClick or alt+rightClick only works if we can find a gap or an edge that let us click directly on the gnome panel, not on its indicators/widgets; I wonder if there is some way to configure it/call its properties if the panel is completely full and without the edges showing?

Comment: wow. what was the reason to make this more complex than just right clicking?

Answer (score 21):

1.Hold left click 
2.Hold alt
3.right click

Comment: this one was new to me but it does indeed work.

Comment: this works when using compiz instead of metacity **14.04**

Answer (score 7):

Hold in <kbd>ALT</kbd> while <kbd>right-clicking</kbd>.

Tested in Ubuntu 12.04 with GNOME Classic.

Comment: This does not work in Oneric -- if you did try it and it worked for you, you should specify your distro and version.

Answer (score 4):

windowkey+alt+rightclick(on panel)

Comment: FYI, the super-key mentioned above is the window-key.

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to say, even though the question is old and was marked as answered, that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> or <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> haven't worked for me for a looooong time. Today I found that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>RightClick</kbd> DOES work. Hope that it helps (even though you may harm your fingers with this combo).

[Source](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1968949)

Comment: Confirmed, this works for me (although Alt+Super+RightClick also works)

Answer (score 1):

Super (hold) + Alt (hold) + Right Mouse Button (click)